# How do I create a list of all existing unique permutations within each category?

Tags: excel, permutation

I would like to create a list of all existing unique pairs of items that belong to each category.

The input table looks like this:

| Category | Item |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 4 |
| C | 5 |

The output table should look like this:

| Category | Item1 | Item2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| A | 1 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 4 |
| B | 1 | 2 |
| C | 4 | 5 |

Massive thanks in advance for your help.

I just can´t figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub CreatePairs()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim cat As String, item1 As String, item2 As String
Dim currentRow As Long
currentRow = 1

For i = 2 To lastRow
cat = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
item1 = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value


For j = i + 1 To lastRow
    If ws.Cells(j, 1).Value = cat Then
        item2 = ws.Cells(j, 2).Value
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
        ws.Cells(currentRow, 3) = cat
        ws.Cells(currentRow, 4) = item1
        ws.Cells(currentRow, 5) = item2
    End If
Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By formula using Excel 365:

```
=LET(
    category, A2:A8,
    item, B2:B8,
    DROP(
        REDUCE(
            {1, 1, 1},
            UNIQUE(category),
            LAMBDA(a, b,
                LET(
                    count, SUM(
                        --(
                            b =
                                category
                        )
                    ),
                    combos, COMBIN(
                        count,
                        2
                    ),
                    start, XMATCH(
                        b,
                        category
                    ) - 1,
                    ind, TOCOL(
                        MAKEARRAY(
                            count,
                            count,
                            LAMBDA(
                                r,
                                c,
                                IF(
                                    c >
                                        r,
                                    100 *
                                        r +
                                        c,
                                    0
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    sel, FILTER(
                        ind,
                        ind > 0
                    ),
                    VSTACK(
                        a,
                        HSTACK(
                            IF(
                                SEQUENCE(
                                    combos
                                ),
                                b
                            ),
                            INDEX(
                                item,
                                sel /
                                    100 +
                                    start
                            ),
                            INDEX(
                                item,
                                MOD(
                                    sel,
                                    100
                                ) +
                                    start
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        1
    )
)
```

[image]

The basic idea is just to get the row and column of the upper triangular part of a 2d array and use it to index the items for each group. So if there are three items in a group:

```
1,1 1,2 1,3
2,1 2,2 2,3
3,1 3,2 3,3
```

use 1,2 1,3 and 2,3.